# Trouble in associations model, I can't create model object in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create in rails console object but I am having trouble using the associations

So I have three models `User`, `Event`, `Participant`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :participants
  has_many :events, through: :participants
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :participants
  has_many :user, through: :participants
end

class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

My factories are

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :event do
    user
  end
end 

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :participant do
    user
    event
  end
end
```

When I run `event = FactoryGirl.build(:event)`, I get the following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<User:0x007f95cae313d8>
    from /Users/german/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'...
```

I think so is about associations in the model I remove `has_many :events` from User and `belongs_to :user` from event and work but, I want to know why?

Comment: The `:user` factory is also relevant, can you please include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation between your Event class and User is a bit off. it should be `has_many :users` not `:user`.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :participants
  has_many :users, through: :participants
end
```

Comment: On a side note I would call the join model [Participation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/participation) as it is more sematically correct.